# Best, most easily-themed mailing/newsletter setup?

Tags: mailing-list, newsletter

Currently theming MailPress, finding it somewhat annoying as a PHP novice.

Any suggestions?

(new to Wordpress... this was easy with Drupal)

Answer (score 1):

Bit subjective this, but the mailchimp plugin is really good. I've been using it for ages and have had some good success at styling it.

Comment: I also just switched to Mailchimp (I was using Feedburner's very basic email service previously). They offer a pretty great free version (limited to a certain number of total emails sent/month) which is more than enough for my subscriber base.  If you are already using Feedburner, though, you can check out its simple email subscription features under the 'Publicize' tab.

Comment: you can also pull the data out, and just use it as a database.